# Google Maps API not authorized from Flutter app

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm fairly new to all this so any help is gratefully received. I have a flutter app that calls the Google Maps API. To call the API I pass it my Google API key and in order to try and make it secure I have set up application restrictions in https://console.cloud.google.com/

The problem is that now when I call the Maps API I get the follwoing error:-

```
This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key
```

Below is a screenshot of the settings that I have applied. What have I done wrong?

[image: The settings I have applied]

UPDATE: Some more information

The relevant APIs are enabled. The SHA-1 Fingerprint is correct. My app is running in debug mode, the certificate is the debug one. If I unrestrict the API key then everything runs okay.

Comment: Is the Maps SDK for Android enabled on your project? Is the SHA-1 fingerprint you added to the key's restrictions correct? (i.e. is it the debug certificate or the release certificate, is your app run in debug or release mode?) If you unrestrict your API key completely, does your map load? Is your project linked to a billing account that is enabled and in good standing?

Comment: @evan Yes the maps SDK for Android is enabled. Double checked the SHA-Fingerprint nu,erous times, it's definately correct. My app is running in debug mode, the certificate is the debug one. If I unrestrict the SPI key then everything runs okay. It is linked to a good billing account.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm then it can only be due to the restriction being incorrect. Please double check that the package name and sha-1 fingerprint are indeed correct for your app. If the problem persists I recommend you contact Google Maps Platform's tech support team https://developers.google.com/maps/support#creating-a-support-case